# Google trends graph is not the same as the csv

Tags: csv

When you check out a search term in google trends. I used hackaday. You get a chart showing that the high point is December 2005 with a 100 interest. If you export the csv the interest for December 2005 is about 45. I have two images showing this. One is plotted in excel and the other is the graph given. I used all the default search options.

Why is it doing this? Which set of data is correct?

Csv plotted in excel:

[image: http://imgur.com/T57HM9i,3rCy20D#0]

Google trends graph:

[image: http://imgur.com/T57HM9i,3rCy20D#1]

Answer (score 0):

That is because the CSV is giving you the data in weekly granularity, trying to be more research-oriented, while the trends graph shows you the data in *monthly* granularity.

In your case it seems that there are 4 weeks with ~40 interest data, while the (weekly) peak that reaches the 100 (which is used to scale the entire graph) has the points next to it on less than 20, so it seems like the data is consistent.